# Angular Virtual Scroll(vs-reapt) does not work for the table

Tags: angularjs

I have a table that shows huge number of data and as result the browser gets stuck.obviously it is because of large amount of data that is being passed.I'm dealing with 10000+ data in this table.

i have tried to fixed using "Angular Virtual Scroll". but it didn't work well.

```
<div class="col-md-8"  id="events" vs-repeat="50">
  <br/>

  <table class="table">          
    <thead>
    <th>Select</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Time</th>
   <th>Log Information</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody vs-repeat>
   <tr ng-repeat="s in events">

     <!--<td style="display:none;">{{ s._id }}</td>-->
    <td><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="s.checked" ng-true-value="1"  ng-false-value="0"></td>
   <td>
    <div >
     <div class="">

        <i ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ s.dat }}

     </div>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div >
     <div >
       {{ s.tim}}
     </div>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div>
     <div >
       {{ s.details}}
     </div>
    </div>
   </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller-

```
  $scope.events;
    function getEventsOfUploadedFile()
    {
        Event.getUploadRead()
        .success(function(event){
        $scope.events=event;
        })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load event data: ';
        });
    }
```

can anyone help me to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: I think you use setTimeout

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

use timeout like below :

```
$scope.events = [];
function getEventsOfUploadedFile()
{
    Event.getUploadRead()
    .success(function(event){
        var i = 0;
        function pushEvent(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                 $scope.events.push(event[i]);
                 i++;
                 if(i < event.length){
                     pushEvent();
                 }
            }, 0);
        }
    }).error(function (error) {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load event data: ';
    });
}
```

Comment: @MSKP d'not use 'vs-repeat'

Comment: it's also stuck

Comment: yes.it is getting stuck because of large amount of data.